# @Override Java Parent Class

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation, overriding

**This is my code in parent class**

```
public boolean ChoiceOfItem(){
    if (bread)
        this.Choice("bread");
    if (meat)
        this.Choice("meat");
    if (lettuce)
        this.Choice("lettuce");
    if (tomato)
        this.Choice("tomato");
    if (carrot)
        this.Choice("carrot");
    return false;
}
```

**and this one is from extended(Not parent) class:**

```
@Override
public boolean ChoiceOfItem() {
    if (ryeBread)
        this.Choice("ryeBread");
    return false;
}
```

My question is what is wrong and what is right here?
Looking forward to your messages. I'll be able to send the whole code if it is necessary.

Comment: Well... "what is wrong" - you tell us! What is your issue?

Comment: you should call `return super.ChoiceOfItem()` in the extended class instead of just false

Comment: You should edit this question and provide, at least: 1) What is the expected result of the code (What are you trying to achieve?) 2) What is the actual result of your code (What happens, and why is it wrong?)
Otherwise you might end up with the question being closed.

Comment: I'd like to hear where all these boolean values like `bread`, `meat`, and so on come from.

Comment: I am the beginner for OOPL. So it is not so easy to adapt it, and I'm really trying to learn it, Marvin Thanks Jérémie B and Martin Nielsen. ChiefTwoPencils it is on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChoiceOfItem probably needs to return true when handled some item, hence return false only in that case.

```
public boolean choiceOfItem(){
    if (bread)
        this.Choice("bread");
    else if (meat)
        this.Choice("meat");
    else if (lettuce)
        this.Choice("lettuce");
    else if (tomato)
        this.Choice("tomato");
    else if (carrot)
        this.Choice("carrot");
    else return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean choiceOfItem() {
    if (super.choiceOfItem())
        return true;
    if (ryeBread) {
        this.Choice("ryeBread");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think I sort it out by changing code as below 

`@Override
          public boolean ChoiceOfItem() {
          super.ChoiceOfItem();
          if (ryeBread) {
            this.Choice("ryeBread");
            return true;
            }
           return false;
        }`

Thanks for advice P.S: Sorry, I could not make it legible

Answer (score 0):

At first to say that those methods all the time return false. The @Override is just a marker to tell the compiler that the method is overriden. This makes sense when you for example change the method signature of the parent class so the compiler tells you in the subclasses that you are not overriding here anymore.